# How to get multiple radio buttons value in another php page?

Tags: php

I have multiple questions and each question has 4 answers, I display all questions and their answers in PHP, by:

```
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) 
  {
   echo "question:".$row['question']."<br>";
  ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="id[<?php echo $row[id] ?>]" value="<?php echo $row[id]    ?>" />
  <?php echo $row['op1'] ?>
  <input type="radio" name="opt[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['op1'] ?>-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" /><br>
   <?php echo $row['op2'] ?>
  <input type="radio" name="opt[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['op2'] ?><?php echo $row['id'] ?>" /><br>
  <?php echo $row['op3'] ?>
  <input type="radio" name="opt[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['op3'] ?><?php echo $row['id'] ?>" /><br>
  <?php echo $row['op4'] ?>
   <input type="radio" name="opt[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['op4'] ?><?php echo $row['id'] ?>" /><br>

 <?php
  }

 ?>
  <input type="submit"  value="answer" /><br>
```

How can I get radio button value  for each $row['id'] on the next page.

Comment: Put the answers in and array and pass the array on to the other page.

Comment: Do you mean the chosen radio button? Or the values of all radio buttons whether selected or not?

Comment: i pass in array but how to get that array such that que 1 - radio button value, que 2- radio button value

Comment: only choosen radio button value and corrosponding question id.

Answer (score 0):

use form action as your redirection page and method POST or GET as you prefer, then
try

```
print_r($_POST);// as your method and you could use $_REQUEST
```

for GET method

```
print_r($_GET);
```

you will see radio button value in array,...

if we use `$_GET` method as form attribue then we will retrieve form value by `$_GET`
if we use `$_POST` method as form attribue then we will retrieve form value by `$_POST`

and `$_REQUEST` can retrieve value posted by both method, but `Request` is not a method

Comment: can u write code, please because in last 2 interview these question is asked